# Need to make a bar chart showing incidence of symptoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with a list of symptoms as the first row and 0's and 1's populating the columns specifying if each case has or does not have the symptom. I would like to make a bar chart showing the incidence of each symptom.

For instance:

```
COVID


Case    Fever   Cough    SOB   Fatigue  Results
A        1        1        0     1         Positive
B        0        1        1     1         Positive
D        1        0        1     1         Positive
Z        1        1        1     1         Positive
```

The bar chart should have 4 bars: Fever (height 3), Cough (height 3), SOB (height 3), Fatigue (height 4)

As an added complication this file has both positive and negative cases and I need to take this data only from the positive cases. I left out any negative cases in my example above for simplicity's sake.

I have tried this but it only works for a single symptom:

```
symptoms_plot <- ggplot(subset(COVID, Results == "Positive" & Cough == 1), aes(Cough)) + geom_bar()
```

I also have been able to separate out just the positive cases with this:

```
split_by_result = split(COVID, COVID$Results)
split_by_result[["Positive"]]
```

I realize it would be easier if the data were formatted differently however this is a living document and cases are being added daily and I can not change how cases are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gather the variables and then plot it.

```
library(tidyverse)

COVID %>%
  filter(Results=="Positive") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c("Fever","Cough","SOB","Fatigue")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

---

[image]

---

**Data**:

```
COVID <- read.table(text='
Case    Fever   Cough    SOB   Fatigue  Results
A        1        1        0     1         Positive
B        0        1        1     1         Positive
D        1        0        1     1         Positive
Z        1        1        1     1         Positive', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: These days you can use `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 1):

I've added 2 negative lines to your dummy data for completeness' sake (you said you didn't put any for simplicity, but it's better to include everything).

First, I want to mention that the fact you mention it would be easier if the data was formatted differently is true. However, even if the source of the data is a "living" document, nothing stops you from processing it right before the plot !

```
# load data
dat <- "Case    Fever   Cough    SOB   Fatigue  Results
A        1        1        0     1         Positive
B        0        1        1     1         Positive
D        1        0        1     1         Positive
Z        1        1        1     1         Positive
X        1        1        1     1         Negative
Y        1        1        1     1         Negative"

dat <- read.table(text = dat, h=T)


library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # for melt


dat2plot <- dat[dat$Results == "Positive", ] # select positves
dat2plot <- melt(dat2plot) # format your data for ggplot

ggplot(dat2plot, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")


# in a one-liner :
ggplot(melt(dat[dat$Results=="Positive",]), aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This outputs your plot :
[image]

Comment: These days you can use `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`